# how to import a library in my case MouseKeyHook?

Tags: c#, mousekeyhook

I just started programming in c# and I don't know how to import a library.
I need `"globalmousekeyhook"` in my program.

Can someone can help me? Thank you! ^^

Link to the library: https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple. In Visual Studio, go to `Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console`. Once it has loaded, copy in the command that is on the GitHub page - `nuget install MouseKeyHook2`.

Once it says it is installed, you can start using it immediately. You will most likely get an error saying it doesn't exist in the current context when you write some code using the library, but you can hover over the help IntelliSense gives you, and it should give you the option to use the library.

If you need more help on using NuGet, [check this out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

In the github link you posted you can see that they provide a  NuGet Package. You can import NuGet Packages into your project :). You can do this using the commandline or Visual Studio.
You can find more information in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

If you're using visual studio, you can install via NuGet:

In the menu bar, choose Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

In the powershell that popups up on the bottom of the screen, type 'nuget install MouseKeyHook'. That should install and give access to the package.

[Check this link for more info on NuGet Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio)